# How to apply multiple times to setInterval loops

Tags: jquery, setinterval, addclass

total novice here. I have a script that uses setInterval to filter through a list and adds/removes a class every 2 seconds to each list item.

How could I edit this script so that I can apply different times for each setInterval loop?

For instance: For the first list item, I want the setInterval (or the delay) to be 3 seconds, the second list item I want it to be 1.5 seconds, and so on and so on until the list is finished... I need each loop to be timed differently. How can do this? **Your help is greatly appreciated.**

```
$(function() {
var $list = $('#animation li');
    $list.filter(':first').addClass('go');

    setInterval(function() {
      if( $list.filter('.go').index() !== $list.length - 1 ) {
      $list.filter('.go').removeClass('go').next().addClass('go');
      }
    else {
      $list.removeClass('go').filter(':first').addClass('go');
      }
   }, 2000);
```

Comment: This means that by your fifth element, you'll be setting interval for 0.09th of a second. What's the purpose of having a decaying interval? You're going to end up with a overflow of events real fast.

Comment: Did some maths, starting at 3 seconds, it will take 6 seconds for your function to be continually firing to infinity. [Calculated on Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&a=*C.sum-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=6/2^k&f=Sum.sumfunction_6/2^k&f3=1&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit_1&f4=infinity&f=Sum.sumupperlimit_infinity&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Sum.sumvariable---.*--)

Answer (score 3):

Very primitive example, but just showing methodology:

```
var $list = $('#animation li');
var worker = function(){
  //
  // perform your process(es)
  //

  // only continue on if necessary
  if (continue_working)
    timer = setTimeout(worker, Math.random() * 5 * 1000);
}
var timer = setTimeout(worker, 2000);

// to stop at any time
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: +1 was working on a similiar answer. setTimeout is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

calling setInterval within setInterval.

```
var intervalFunc = new function(){
    if( $list.filter('.go').index() !== $list.length - 1 ) {
  $list.filter('.go').removeClass('go').next().addClass('go');
  }
else {
  $list.removeClass('go').filter(':first').addClass('go');
  }
  // Calculate the next time func
  var timeout = ...
  setInterval(intervalFunc, timeout);
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi Guys I'm a total novice here. I guess setTimeout is the way to go, I'm not sure. I need a jquery script that adds a class to a list item and then removes that class after a predetermined time. It sneed to cycle through about 10 list items each with a different time delay